# Serialize jQuery Variables

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to make an AJAX POST to a php script and send over the following variables. I had a look at the jQuery documentation but I struggled to understand its' use anywhere outside of forms.

```
var amount = $('input[name=amount]').val();
var chance = $('input[name=chance]').val();
```

These are two decimal values, how could I format them to send them as the data field in an AJAX post request?

If `serialize()` is not the way to go, what is?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
var amount = $('input[name=amount]').val();
var chance = $('input[name=chance]').val();
var params = 'amount='+amount+'&chance='+chance;
jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'path.php',
   data: params,
   success: function(e){
        //...
   }
});
```

The php would then receive those variables like below:

```
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$chance = $_POST['chance'];
echo $amount . ' and ' . $chance;
```

Comment: like $_POST['amount']

Comment: Would you mind editing the ajax call to show me where a function could be carried out based on the response of the call?

Comment: perfect thanks. I assume function(e) is just a random name we assign to the code that will be preformed in the brackets.